# Combine multiple bindParam in mySQL width PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm new to PDO and actually it's a little bit complicated.

Is it possbile to combine these params

```
$stmt->bindParam(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':telephone', $telephone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':fax', $fax, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':mobile', $mobile, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
```

to one array? Is it meaningful or should I keep it as it is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this

```
          $stmt->execute(array(
                        ':firstname' => $firstname,
                        ':lastname' => $lastname ,
                        ':telephone' => $telephone,
                        ':fax' => $fax,
                        ':mobile' => $mobile
                           ));
```

Comment: in what is it different from what I suggested?

Comment: But where is the PDO::PARAM_STR?

Answer (score 1):

I remember having done something like this in the past:

```
$arr = array();
$arr[':firstname'] = $firstname;
$arr[':lastname'] = $lastname;
$arr[':telephone'] = $telephone;
$arr[':fax'] = $fax;
$arr[':mobile'] = $mobile;
$stmt->execute($arr);
```

Since you're not using any fancy parameter type it should do it.

---

Yes, I confirm this is what I'm doing and it works. See an extract of my personal code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `tbl` (relid, `type`, `table`, `name`) VALUES (:PARAM1, :PARAM2, :PARAM3, :PARAM4)";

$stmt = $cn->prepare($sql);

$arrQP = array();
$arrQP[":PARAM1"] = $key;
$arrQP[":PARAM2"] = $arrRel[0];
$arrQP[":PARAM3"] = $arrRel[1];
$arrQP[":PARAM4"] = $arrRel[2];

$stmt->execute($arrQP);
```

Comment: Have you tested this?

Comment: Sorry, from memory. I'm not having my code right now but I'm pretty sure it is it / edited: yes it is tested